# Shortcut to create new php file in windows

Tags: windows-7

There are shortcuts to create new files in explorer (one that I use is Alt+F+W+T). But it just creates a new text file.

Being a developer, **I wanted to know is there any such shortcut for creating a php file directly?** (I currently rename the txt file to php)

Comment: @ekaj Hadn't tried it again as I hadn't seen the edit. Will surely try this when I get time. Thanks btw :)

Comment: And? Did this work?

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

1. Navigate to the directory where you installed PHP,make a text document, and
   rename it untitled.php
2. Open the registry editor using by using the start menu's search
   function and typing RegEdit
3. Find the .php key in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, and create a subkey called
   ShellNew
4. In ShellNew, create a new String Value with the name `ItemName`, and
   the data should be to your untitled PHP file (Mine is
   `@%SystemRoot%\Programs\PHPApache\untitled.php,-470`, for example (I'm not sure what the ,-470 means, but I put it there because .txt files had it as well)). Just
   redirect this to the correct path for your installation.
5. Then make a new Expandable String Value and name it `NullFile`
6. Go to your desktop, right click, and it should show an option for a
   new PHP file.

This should be correct, but I had some difficulties following the guide I had originally posted, sorry, and once I got it to work correctly I couldn't remember the exact steps. This should work correctly, however, if not tell me so. To get this list of steps I looked at the values for a .txt document, since you are also able to make a new text document by right clicking.

Comment: It says the key `phpfile` already exists (in step3), so gives an error..